# How to click a particular button within a window (without using XPOS YPOS)

Tags: window, autohotkey, buttonclick

I have just started using AUTOHOTKEY and its been phenomenal.I have a doubt though.
I want to automate the launching of an application and then clicking on a specific button in it.I would like to accomplish this using AHK.

Once I launch the applicaton this window appears [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkmoccc4hhhxmng/LOGIN%20screenshot.jpg).
I want to hit the "Connect" button, but I cant figure out a good way to move the cursor to the connect button. I tried the following code which uses tab.

```
Loop ,5
    {    
sleep 2*1000    
Send {Tab down}    
}
```

**This works, But i feel this is crude and need a better way. Is there a way to use button_name or button_text to my advantage?**

**I dont want to use screen positions XPOS AND YPOS either.**

The link to my applcn window screenshot is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkmoccc4hhhxmng/LOGIN%20screenshot.jpg).

I have the following info from the WINDOW-SPY feature of **AutoHotKey**.Hope you can find this useful.

> > > > > > > > > > ( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > >                     Asianet Login
> > > > > > > > > >                     ahk_class QWidget
> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > ( Mouse Position )<<<<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         On Screen:  881, 306  (less often used)
> > > > > > > > > > > >                         In Active Window:   462, 76
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > ( Now Under Mouse Cursor )<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > >                   ClassNN:    QWidget2
> > > > > > > > >                   Text:   bnConnect
> > > > > > > > >                   Color:  0xC8D0D4  (Blue=C8 Green=D0 Red=D4)
> > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > ( Active Window Position )<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > >                     left: 419     top: 230     width: 529     height: 238
> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > ( Status Bar Text )<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > ( Visible Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > > >                       layoutWidget
> > > > > > > > > > >                       bnConnect
> > > > > > > > > > >                       bnAbout
> > > > > > > > > > >                       bnClose
> > > > > > > > > > >                       chkRemember
> > > > > > > > > > >                       edPassword
> > > > > > > > > > >                       lbPassword
> > > > > > > > > > >                       edUsername
> > > > > > > > > > >                       teLog
> > > > > > > > > > >                       qt_scrollarea_viewport
> > > > > > > > > > >                       lbUsername
> > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > ( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<
> > > > > > > > > > >                       qt_scrollarea_vcontainer
> > > > > > > > > > >                       qt_scrollarea_hcontainer
> > > >
> > > > ( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<
> > > >
> > > > ( TitleMatchMode=slow Hidden Text )<<<<

Comment: You shouldnt add links to dropbox images that you later delete. It makes your post way less useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

Use ControlClick:

```
ControlClick, ClassNN QWidget2, ahk_class QWidget, , Left, 1
```

Maybe use the WinTitle instead, tried this with the save as window from Notepad.

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2
ControlClick, Button1, Save As, , Left, 1
```

So That would be for Asianet Login:

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2
ControlClick, QWidget2, Asianet Login, , Left, 1
```

Assuming that you hovered over the LogIn button when you made the AHK Windows Spy snapshot.

Comment: Hi Robert,
I tried this just now. ControlClick does not work.

Comment: @robert-ilbrink in ControlClick, ClassNN QWidget2, ahk_class QWidget, , Left, 1 are any params that need to be changed?